# Problemas al agregar un nuevo registro

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

Hola de nuevo comunidad,

estoy aprendiendo entity framework y hago un ejercicio donde guardo un expediente con x documentos y ese documento tiene x imágenes.

Al querer insertar nuevos documentos a un expediente ya existente, tengo el siguiente error:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.ObjectDisposedException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll
>
> Additional information: The ObjectContext instance has been disposed and can no longer be used for operations that require a connection.

Tengo un formulario en donde listo los expedientes, luego al seleccionar uno y dar clic a editar, paso el expediente seleccionado a una nueva ventana de detalle, así:

```
Detalles exp = new Detalles(bExpedientes[index]);
```

bExpedientes es una binding list que contiene todos los expedientes existentes, la lleno así:

```
 public static List<Expediente> GetExpedientes()
    {
        Entities context = new Entities();
        List<Expediente> exp = new List<Expediente>();
        using (context)
        {
            try
            {
                exp = context.Expediente.ToList();
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                return null;
            }
            return exp;
       }
    }
```

Luego, en detalles, tengo un botón para agregar nuevos documentos así:

```
expediente.Documentos.Add(new Documento { NombreDocumento = txtNomDoc.Text, FechaCreacion = DateTime.Now, idExpediente = idExpediente })
```

donde expediente, es una instancia de la clase Expediente generada por EF.
ahí es donde entra el problema, al ejecutar esa linea tira la excepción antes mencionada. Tengo entendido que puede ser por el using que pongo al extraer los expedientes. Pero alguna idea de como solucionarlo?

Luego guardo todos esos documentos nuevos en una binding list llamada bDocumentos, así:

```
Doc = expediente.Documentos.ToList();
            dgvDocumentos.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
            bDocumentos = new BindingList<Documento>(Doc);
            dgvDocumentos.DataSource = bDocumentos;
```

para luego al dar clic a un botón guardar, pasar las listas a una función que hará el guardado. Cuando inserto nuevos Expedientes con nuevos documentos y nuevas imágenes no tengo problemas. Pero al agregar nuevos documentos a un expediente existente si!

Lo que hace el botón guardar es lo siguiente:

```
General.GuardarDatos(bDocumentos, bArchivo);
```

Aquí, paso las listas. La de archivo por el momento no es relevante. El metodo GuardarDatos hace lo siguiente:

```
public static void GuardarDatos(Expediente expediente,BindingList<Documento> documentos, BindingList<Archivo> archivos)
    {
        Entities context = new Entities();
        using (context)
        {
            foreach(var documento in documentos)
            {
                if(documento.idDocumento == 0)
                {
                    context.Documento.Add(documento);
                }
                else
                {
                    DocumentoNG.actualizarDocumento(documento);
                }
                foreach(var archivo in archivos)
                {
                    if (documento.idDocumento == 0)
                    {
                        context.Archivo.Add(archivo);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        ArchivoNG.actualizarArchivo(archivo);
                    }
                }
            }
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
```

Si quito el using, el error lo tira al ejecutar la linea actualizarDocumento sin embargo es otro es decir:

An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll

Additional information: An entity object cannot be referenced by multiple instances of IEntityChangeTracker.

y ese metodo lo que hace es lo siguiente:

```
 public static void actualizarDocumento(Documento documento)
    {
        Entities context = new Entities();
        using (context)
        {
            context.Documento.Attach(documento);
            var registro = context.Entry(documento);
            registro.Property(t => t.NombreDocumento).IsModified = true;
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
```

La entidad expediente es así:

```
 public partial class Expediente
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public Expediente()
    {
        this.Documentos = new HashSet<Documento>();
    }

    public int idExpediente { get; set; }
    public string NombreExpediente { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime FechaCreacion { get; set; }
    public string DuenioExpediente { get; set; }
    public int CantidadDocumento { get; set; }

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<Documento> Documentos { get; set; }
}
```

La de documento es así:

```
public partial class Documento
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public Documento()
    {
        this.Archivo = new HashSet<Archivo>();
    }

    public int idDocumento { get; set; }
    public int idExpediente { get; set; }
    public string NombreDocumento { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime FechaCreacion { get; set; }

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<Archivo> Archivo { get; set; }
    public virtual Expediente Expediente { get; set; }
}
```

Gracias de ante mano.

Comment: No he leído la pregunta todavia, pero de una vez te puedo decir que ese bloque `catch` no es buena idea.

Comment: Cúal catch? El de getExpedientes?

Comment: Sí, ese. mi comentario no tiene nada que ver con tu error o tu pregunta. Solo te aviso que el devolver `null` e ignorar la excepción quje salta no es una buena idea. Esto solo resultará en un `NullReferenceException` mas adelante en tu código sin tener los detalles de la excepción original que causó tu problema. Mejor es quitar el `try-catch`, y si salta una excepción, pues que salte. Por lo menos no habrá misterio en cuanto a la causa del problema y como corregirlo.

Comment: Oh bien, gracias por el comentario, tenes razón. :D

Comment: Alguna idea de cómo corregir mi error? Intenté quitando el using de getExpedientes, pero luego me tiraba otro error por el dispose.

Comment: El problema definitivamente tiene que ver con el momento en que le haces `Dispose` a tu `context`. Pero en cuanto a proponerte una solución, tengo ideas, pero los fragmentos de código en tu pregunta no son suficiente para poder estar seguro de lo que propongo. Necesitaría un verdadero [mcve] para tener el cuadro completo.

Comment: Jmmm uno del ciclo completo? Lo que sucede después?

Comment: Hay algo que no entiendo, ¿cuál es tu Dbcontext? ¿Entities? ¿Expediente? ¿son lo mismo solo que las nombras de distinta forma? Aparte, trata siempre de instanciar el context conm un bloque using, y solo para una o dos operaciones, así evitas que quede abierto el dbcontext, o que lo cierres y luego lo intentes usar en otro lado. Trata de crear métodos específicos, por ejemplo: AgregarDocumento(), y le pasas por parámetros la información, y dentro de ese método haces using al dbcontext y guardas el documento, de esa forma tienes mejor control de lo que haces.

Comment: Mi context es Entities, como expliqué en la pregunta, expediente es una instancia de la clase Expediente generada por EF en referencia a la tabla Expediente.

Comment: Alex: Suficiente para que podamos reproducir el error que experimentas. sin eso, pudiera proponerte cosas que son generalmente buenas, pero que tal vez no apliquen a tu caso, o que tal vez te causen otro error por otro lado, etc...  Tal vez la solución sea mantener un context activo mientras el formulario esté activo, tal vez sea mejor abrir y cerrar los contexts en cada método como lo sugiere @Luis. No tengo claro qué es lo mejor para ti con lo poco que puedo ver.

Comment: Entiendo, entonces ".Documentos" es una propiedad de navegación de tu entidad. Intenta agregar ".AsNoTracking() a tu query: exp = context.Expediente.AsNoTracking().ToList(); Lo mas seguro es que entity framework esté aplicando trakcing (cacheo) en la búsqueda, y al cerrar el dbcontext (cuando cierras el using), .Documents deja de existir.

Comment: @Luis: Lo intenté y ahora me tira la siguiente excpeción: 
An unhandled exception of type 'System.ObjectDisposedException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll

Additional information: The ObjectContext instance has been disposed and can no longer be used for operations that require a connection.

Comment: También agrega .Documents para que te traiga ese dato: exp = context.Expediente.AsNoTracking().Include(e => e.Documents).ToList(); De esta forma te materializa la propiedad. Debes incluir : using System.Data.Entity;

Comment: @sstan: Ahorita agrego lo que hace después.

Comment: Ya incluí el resto del código. @Luis: intenté lo que me dijiste, pero al hacer el ".include(e=>e.x)" no habia no podía seleccionar Documentos porque no lo detectaba.

Comment: ¿Podrías agregar tu entidad expediente? Para ver como es la estructura, igual y no tienes creadas propiedades de navegación.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/69871/discussion-between-alex-varela-and-luis).

Answer (score 0):

Prueba lo así

```
public static void GuardarDatos(Expediente expediente,BindingList<Documento> documentos, BindingList<Archivo> archivos)
    {
        Entities context = new Entities();
        using (context)
        {
            foreach(var documento in documentos)
            {
                if(documento.idDocumento == 0)
                {
                    context.Documento.Add(documento);
                    context.SaveChanges();
                }
                else
                {
                    DocumentoNG.actualizarDocumento(documento);
                    context.SaveChanges();
                }
                foreach(var archivo in archivos)
                {
                    if (documento.idDocumento == 0)
                    {
                        context.Archivo.Add(archivo);
                        context.SaveChanges();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        ArchivoNG.actualizarArchivo(archivo);
                        context.SaveChanges();
                    }
                }
            }
   }
}
```

Comment: No me expliqué bien, editaré la pregunta, gracias!